# Different currentTime for same video on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I want to get the `currentTime` for a video when video ends. But for different browsers, for the same video, `currentTime` returns different values after the third or forth digits after decimal. For ex. for particular video of length 30 seconds I am testing, `currentTime` value when video ends returns `30.069841` in Chrome and Firefox. But for the same video, it returns `30.0683333` in IE edge and Safari. Why is there a difference? And is there any way I can get the unique value in all the browsers?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your frame rate is something that cannot be expressed as a finite decimal number (or precisely expressed in a floating point number), which the value `30.0683333` looks like, it may be up to the browser to decide how to represent them. What is the frame rate of the video? Could it be 30fps by any chance? You could transcode it to e.g. 25fps and check then. If the video has an audio track then the audio time scale could come in play too. You could use ffmpeg to dump the actual timestamps of the video frames in the timescale expressed as a fractional number and then looking at the timestamp of the last frame you could try to understand what would be the decimal value. But you should provide more info on the timescale of the video and if it has an audio track.